# Can I partially translate a section?

Tags: localization

I have a section called `stories` and a section called `news`.

`stories` needs to have Russian translations

So i set up multisite and Russian language and fields as translation method - for each language

Great - I can view story entry in Russian with the URL prefixed as domain/ru/story

My problem is that I only want that content translated not the rest of the site URLs which by default seem to all inherit 'ru'.

I can for the purposes of this particular project just setup a Russian section for stories and do away with the whole Craft multi site language setup. But I like to keep things crafty if possible.

Is there a solution to using translations just for a section and leaving the rest of the site in English?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but seems like you could just not enable Russian in all of the other sections except for "Stories"?

Comment: It's all in english - except I want stories section to be Russian and english. But once localisation is activated then my Russian stories section has a sidebar with links to news items. These have ru in the url. Plus some views that are template only seem to break